# PHP/HTML how do you creat a drop down list that open another drop down list?

Tags: php, html

All,
I am writting a php script that runs as part of a joomla site.  I have a table
Event
  day;
  time;
  races;  (is an array of race id's)
  ....

here is the Race table
Race
  id;
  name;
  ...

On the site I want to have a drop down list of table Event.  When they click on an Event in that list, I want to open a second drop down list on that page of possible races (using the values of the Event.races for my query).  Any idea on how to get the first drop down selected so I can create the second on the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [Son of Suckerfish menu](http://htmldog.com/articles/suckerfish/dropdowns/) system.  This is something you'll need some creative CSS to accomplish, but these guys have already done it and it's pretty easy to implement.

Comment: I ended up going with variation of this http://www.cafewebmaster.com/pure-css-mouseover-menu-without-javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with jQuery + an ajax request (aka XMLHttpRequest).

Comment: I ended up going with variation of this cafewebmaster.com/pure-css-mouseover-menu-without-javascript